# How to load all files from a jar added as Maven dependency in a Tomcat webapp?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, jar

Before marking it duplicate please read the whole post!

I have to read all files under the `profiles` folder in a `jar` which is a Maven dependency:

[image: jar structure]

Below is the code which I am using for reading files:

```
CodeSource cs = Detector.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
public List<String> pr = new ArrayList<>(); 
if (cs != null) {
    URL jar = cs.getLocation();
    ZipInputStream zip = null;
    try {
        zip = new ZipInputStream(jar.openStream());
        while (true) {
            ZipEntry entry = zip.getNextEntry();
            if (entry == null)
                break;
            String ename = entry.getName();
            if (ename.startsWith("profiles/")) {
                try(InputStream in =
                      Detector.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(ename)) {
                    pr.add(IOUtils.toString(in));
                }
            }
        }
        DetectorFactory.loadProfile(pr);
    } 
}
```

When I use this code in a standalone Java project it works fine and files are being read but when I use the same code in a Tomcat webapp it does not. However as per my observation, it seems to be a Tomcat's `ClassLoader` issue because in the Java application the class loader is `LauncherAppClassLoader` whereas in webapp it is the `ParallelWebAppClassLoader`.

Comment: Is this `langdetect-....jar` under your control or under the control of someone you know?

Comment: I have added it as a Maven dependency

Comment: I know. You said that. But you can also add your own (company's) artifacts as Maven dependencies. They don't have to come from external by all means. But I think [it is in your case](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Clangdetect), right? BTW, there's a newer version (`1.1.2-20151117`) on Maven Central with an extended `groupId`. This is [a project on GitHub](https://github.com/shuyo/language-detection). Why don't you simply fork it and do with its contents whatever you want to do as long as the license allows it.

Comment: Try removing "getClassLoader()" from the Detector... line.

Comment: @Stefan I had already tried it before posting here, none works.

Comment: I've just looked at the data you're loading on github (e.g.https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shuyo/language-detection/master/profiles/uk). You could of course read it directly from github by iterating through the list of language codes you're interested in and altering the url appropriately.

Comment: @EngineerDollery You are suggesting me to make unnecessary server calls each time I need to detect any text, instead I would go with the alternative of adding these files to resources folder.